# ie8 jquery addclass object does not support this property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a asp:textbox in a user control on my page. From a js file, I have my code as:

```
$get(_dropdownID).addClass('dropdownTextDisabled');
```

This is giving me an error while running in IE8: Object does not support this method or property.
Reason for trying this is that IE8 does not seem to support className. Earlier code was:

```
dropdown.className = "dropdownTextDisabled";
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are writing something wrong here:

```
$get(_dropdownID).addClass('dropdownTextDisabled');
```

shuold be

```
$('#_dropdownID').addClass('dropdownTextDisabled');
```

does it work in other browsers? What is the variable `$get` you are calling the method addClass() on?

Comment: _dropdownID is the ClientID of the textbox control. 
Even if I am using 
$('#' + _dropdownID).addClass('dropdownTextDisabled'); 
this is giving me an error saying Object expected.

Comment: does your code work in other browser?Can you post the html Markup?

Comment: Yes the code with className worked in IE6,7. Now, since its failing in IE8, I have to resolve it.

Comment: But failing means that the class is not added or that you don't see the result of adding it to the textbox?

Comment: means that I dont see the result of adding the class to the textbox in IE8. I mentioned it the beginning: "Earlier code was: dropdown.className = "dropdownTextDisabled";".

Comment: Have you looked at this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144432/asp-net-jquery-hover-event-gives-out-object-expected-error)? It might help you.

Comment: This one could be useful too: it could be a problem in the loading of jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312150/where-should-a-script-block-with-jquery-code-be-placed-on-an-asp-net-mvc-master-p

Answer (score 0):

[`$get`](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/08/the_everuseful_get_and_find_as.html) is an ASP.NET AJAX shortcut which returns a DOM element, whereas [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) is a jQuery function (which can only be used on jQuery objects).

Try this instead:

```
$('#<%= _dropdownID.ClientID %>').addClass('dropdownTextDisabled');
```

This is based on the assumption that `_dropdownID` is the ID of your ASP.NET `DropDownList` control.

If `_dropdownID` is simply the ID of an HTML `<select>`, do this:

```
$('#_dropdownID').addClass('dropdownTextDisabled');
```

Comment: _dropdownID is the ClientID itself. 
Also, $('#<%= _dropdownID.ClientID %>') is giving me an error.

Comment: @S Mukherjee: Is your drop-down list an ASP.NET `DropDownList` or is it an HTML `<select>` ?  If it's the former, use its ID in place of `_dropdownID`.  If it's the latter, I've updated my answer with the relevant code.

Comment: Well, actually it is a asp.net textbox which is given a look of dropdown by giving it a background image of an arrow.

Comment: @S Mukherjee: Use the first syntax then, replacing `_dropdownID` with the ID of your `TextBox` control.

Comment: I did a quick 
alert($get("textbox1")) 
where the css class was assigned...it gave null. So using only the textbox id wont help as it is inside a user control.